# What is compile in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga

I'm newbie on Verilog.

In C Programming, build process are roughly as
- preprocessing - compile - assemble - linking

In Verilog, (BOOK : Verilog HDL: A guide to Digital Design and Synthesis), there is described Verilog development and build process are ...
- Design ( and simulation ) - Synthesis (elaboration, apply constraints and so on) - Verification

I think terms "synthesis" is most similar to compile.

But, "Verilog HDL: A guide to Digital Design and Synthesis" describes 'Compiler'(i.e., Compiler directive, `define, `ifdef, etc.)

**Compile** in Verilog means only for simulation target ?

Comment: This just seems like nitpicking about nomenclature. Is there something about the details/specifics that is very important to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing a C build process to elements of the engineering process of a Verilog project, so the terminology isn't going to match up. If you look at just the Verilog build process, it still won't necessarily match because it's quite different. Maybe you could view synthesis as analogous to compiling, mapping to assembling, and linking to placement and routing. But whether that analogy is useful depends on what exactly your goal is with this comparison.

Comment: maybe this is answer for my questions.
https://www.quora.com/What-is-compilation-elaboration-and-simulation-in-VLSI

Comment: Yes, there's some good info there. Simulation is kind of orthogonal to building something that will run on your target platform though. For example, unit tests are a way of simulating C code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing entirely different concepts. The *Design*, *Synthesis*, and *Verification* are **stages** representing different points in chronological time of a project. Those steps share a common source description, in this case Verilog HDL.

The *compile* step is part of a tool's process of reading that source HDL into a form that the tool can act upon. Both simulation and synthesis tool go through the compilation process which create an internal data structure most suitable to the task.